# Install Bundler gem using Ansible

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, bundler, ansible

I am trying to install Bundler on my VPS using Ansible.

I already have rbenv set up and the global ruby is 2.1.0.

If I SSH as root into the server and run `gem install bundler`, it installs perfectly.

I have tried the following three ways of using Ansible to install the Bundler gem and all three produce no errors, but when I SSH in and run `gem list`, Bundler is nowhere to be seen.

Attempt 1:

```
---
- name: Install Bundler
  shell: gem install bundler
```

Attempt 2:

```
---
- name: Install Bundler
  shell: gem install bundler
```

Attempt 3:

```
---
- name: Install Bundler
  gem: name=bundler
       state=latest
```

I have also tried the last attempt with `user_install=yes` and also with `user_install=no` and neither make any difference.

Any ideas how I can get it to install Bundler correctly via Ansible?

I've been working on this for a little while now and I have 1 ruby version installed: 2.1.0 and ahve found that the shims directory for rbenv does not contain a shim for `bundle`.

Should a shim for `bundle` be in there? I'm just getting confused as to why capistrano cannot find the `bundle` command as it's listed when I run `sudo gem list` but NOT when I run `gem list`?

```
root@weepingangel:/usr/local/rbenv/shims# echo $PATH
/usr/local/rbenv/shims:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
root@weepingangel:/usr/local/rbenv/shims# gem environment
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.2.0
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.1.0 (2013-12-25 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /root/.gem/specs
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0
     - /root/.gem/ruby/2.1.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - :sources => ["http://gems.rubyforge.org", "http://gems.github.com"]
     - "gem" => "--no-ri --no-rdoc"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://gems.rubyforge.org
     - http://gems.github.com
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/bin
     - /usr/local/rbenv/libexec
     - /usr/local/rbenv/shims
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /sbin
     - /bin
     - /usr/games
```

Any ideas?

So, I think the two main problems I have:

1. Why is bundler only visible when I run `sudo gem list`?
2. My deploy is saying:

   ```
   INFO [18d5838c] Running /usr/bin/env bundle install --binstubs  
   /var/rails_apps/neiltonge/shared/bin --path  
   /var/rails_apps/neiltonge/shared/bundle --without development test
   --deployment --quiet on 188.226.159.96 DEBUG [18d5838c] Command: cd /var/rails_apps/neiltonge/releases/20140301205432 && ( PATH=$PATH
   /usr/bin/env bundle install --binstubs
   /var/rails_apps/neiltonge/shared/bin --path
   /var/rails_apps/neiltonge/shared/bundle --without development test
   --deployment --quiet ) DEBUG [18d5838c]     /usr/bin/env: bundle: No such file or directory
   ```

   and this is my `$PATH`:

   ```
   /usr/local/rbenv/shims:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
   ```

Why can't bundle be located?

Comment: Right I have found that running `gem list` doesn't show Bundler but `sudo gem list` does! Why is this and where should gem the gem be for Capistrano to be able to use it?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The problem is that, when running `gem install bundler` via ansible, you're not initializing rbenv properly, since `rbenv init` is run in `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`. So the `gem` command used is the system one, not the one installed as a rbenv shim. So whenever you install a gem, it is installed system-wide, not in your rbenv environment.

To have rbenv initialized properly, you must execute bash itself and explicitely state that it's a login shell, so it reads it's initialization files :

```
ansible your_host -m command -a 'bash -lc "gem install bundler"' -u your_rbenv_user
```

Leave the `-u your_rbenv_user` part if you really want to do this as root.

If the above command works, you can easily turn it into a playbook action :

```
- name: Install Bundler
  become_user: your_rbenv_user
  command: bash -lc "gem install bundler"
```

It's cumbersome, but it's the only way I found so far.

Comment: Hey, Perfect! That makes sense and it works correctly. That's another part solved. Next is trying to figure out why the bundle command cannot be found during the deploy by capistrano but I am thinking the issue could be along the same lines.

Comment: Could you please clarify what the lc flags do on the bash command?

Comment: -l : tell bash to act as if it was invoked via a login shell / -c : the command to execute. It's on the first page of `man bash` :)

Comment: Apologies, I did mean to. Thanks!

Comment: @leucos: Can you clarify what do you mean by "your_host"and "command"? Thanks!

Comment: For noobs like me, I guess the command goes like this: `ansible localhost -m command -a 'bash -lc "gem install bundler"' -u vagrant` Please, correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: @PetrCibulka : `your_host` is the host you want to run bundler on; `command` is literally `command`. And yes, if you want to run this on localhost, you are correct. However, ansible has not much added value in this case. Sorry if my reply was unclear.

Comment: Actually it was very helpful! Made my Vagrant hate me a little less. :) Thanks again.

Comment: Great. Use `become_user` instead of `sudo_user` as of 2.x ansible.

Answer (score 16):

Since Ansible 1.3 following native solution is possible:

```
- name: requirements for installing gems
  apt:
    name: {{ item }}
  with_items:
    - ruby
    - ruby-dev
    - make

- name: install gem with proper $PATH
  gem:
    name: xyz
    user_install: no
```

Mention the `user_install` parameter! Additionally some dependecies installed by the *bundler* could need following further package dependencies:

- zlib1g-dev

Comment: Thank you, this helped me out.

Comment: best answer there.

Comment: ```user_install: no``` is for system-wide installation only.

Comment: @ThomasSteinbach Can I add Gemfile instead of a single gem? I basically want to do `bundle install`

Answer (score 2):

I've met the similar environment issue when I tried to run commands as another user. As mentioned in this [feature request](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/4854) you have two options to execute your command in login shell (that will load user environment). For example i'ld like to install bundler as *rails* user:

```
- name: Install Bundler
  shell: gem install bundler
  sudo_user: rails -i
```

or

```
- name: Install Bundler
  command: sudo -iu rails gem install bundler
```

Answer (score 0):

This Worked for me:

```
- name: rubygems | install bundler
  shell: gem install bundler

- name: rbenv | rehash
  shell: RBENV_ROOT={{ rbenv_root }} rbenv rehash
```

Sometimes after installing bundler, with rbenv on the system, you need to update your `$PATH` by runing `rbenv rehash`. I just tried the same thing with ansible, and it worked. Bundler is available in my `$PATH` after rehash.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest and quickest way to install `bundler` using Ansible is this:

Simply install `rbenv` by using the role https://github.com/zzet/ansible-rbenv-role and by configuring its plugins like so (obviously, there are more parameters to configure than just the plugins):

```
rbenv_plugins:
- { name: 'ruby-build',
    repo: 'https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git',
    version: master }
- { name: 'rbenv-default-gems',
    repo: 'https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv-default-gems.git',
    version: master }
```

The included plugin `rbenv-default-gems` will add `bundler` by default and into the right directory during the installation process of the version of `ruby` you will have spcecified.

Then make sure `bundler` is in `PATH`.

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working like this:

```yaml
- name: Install jekyll and bundler                                                                                                                      
  become_user: bob                                                                                                                    
  gem:                                                                                                                                                  
    name: "{{ item }}"                                                                                                                                  
  environment:                                                                                                                                          
    GEM_HOME: /home/bob/gems                                                                                                          
    PATH: $PATH:/bin/:/usr/bin/:/home/bob/gems/bin                                                                                    
  with_items:                                                                                                                                           
    - jekyll                                                                                                                                            
    - bundler
```

Replace `bob` with your local user.

And then use the same principle with the bundler module

```yaml
- name: Install Gems                                                                                                                                    
  become_user: bob                                                                                                                     
  bundler:                                                                                                                                              
    gemfile: /home/bob/Gemfile                                                                                          
    state: present                                                                                                                                      
  environment:                                                                                                                                          
    GEM_HOME: /home/bob/gems                                                                                                           
    PATH: $PATH:/bin/:/usr/bin/:/home/bob/gems/bin
```