# how to install gems for rbenv, using Ansible

Tags: bundler, rbenv, ansible

Using Ansible, how can I use the gem (or other) module to install a gem (in this case, bundler) such that I can run the following command without error?

```
deployer@boxes-vm:~$ ~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle install
rbenv: bundle: command not found
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install Bundler gem using Ansible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22115936/install-bundler-gem-using-ansible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can always use the bundle from the shims directory

```
command: ${HOME}/.rbenv/shims/bundle install --deployment
```